Python setup.py "AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'main'"
I made a project in Python with this project structure:
G:.
│   .gitignore
│   ReadMe.txt
│   requirements.txt
│   setup.py
│
├───.vscode
│       settings.json
│
├───app
│   │   app.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───static
│   │   ├───css
│   │   │       login_styles.css
│   │   │
│   │   ├───fonts
│   │   │       NotoSansDisplay-Regular.ttf
│   │   │
│   │   ├───js
│   │   │       game_script.js
│   │   │       login_script.js
│   │   │
│   │   └───res
│   │       │   3201279.jpg
│   │       │   background_abstract.jpg
│   │       │
│   │       ├───fonts
│   │       │       ARCADECLASSIC.TTF
│   │       │
│   │       └───sprites
│   │           ├───invaders
│   │           │       space__0000_A1.png
│   │           │       space__0001_A2.png
│   │           │       
│   │           └───projectiles
│   │                   missile_1.png
│   │
│   ├───templates
│   │       game.html
│   │       login.html
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           app.cpython-310.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-310.pyc
│
├───instance
│       test.db
│
├───Pflichtenheft
│       Space-Invaders-ReWebed_Pflichtenheft.docx
│
└───tests
        test_01.py

I used the setup.py to create a tar.gz:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='space_invaders_rewebed',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'annotated-types==0.6.0',
        'anyio==4.3.0',
        'blinker==1.7.0',
        'click==8.1.7',
        'colorama==0.4.6',
        'exceptiongroup==1.2.0',
        'Flask==3.0.2',
        'Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1',
        'greenlet==3.0.3',
        'idna==3.6',
        'itsdangerous==2.1.2',
        'Jinja2==3.1.3',
        'MarkupSafe==2.1.5',
        'pydantic==2.6.3',
        'pydantic_core==2.16.3',
        'sniffio==1.3.1',
        'SQLAlchemy==2.0.28',
        'starlette==0.36.3',
        'typing_extensions==4.10.0',
        'Werkzeug==3.0.1'
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'run_space_invaders_rewebed = app:main'
        ]
    }
)


However, when I install my tar.gz in a venv and run my command run_space_invaders_rewebed, I get the following error:
AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'main'
But there's a clearly defined main() in my app.py:
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session, make_response
from models import db, User, Score
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = "super secret key"

    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True

    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('login.html')

    
    return app


def main():
    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


I want my script to execute correctly, but the error doesn't allow me to. How exactly can I fix the error and why is my main() not found?

Your main function is defined in the app.py file, located in the app folder (seen as a module).
Two solutions :
Solution 1
Your entry point should then be defined this way :
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'run_space_invaders_rewebed = app.app:main'
    ]
}

Solution 2
Or you can keep your entry point definition, and add to app/__init__.py the following lines :
from .app import main

__all__ = [main]

This will add the main function to the app module.

The entry-point configuration would follow <package>.<module>:<function> syntax, like:
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'run_space_invaders_rewebed = app.app:main'
    ]
}

